# Canonical way to clip slice of a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I was looking to clip a slice of a sparse matrix. This is fairly easy to do with a dense matrix.

```
import numpy as np
dense_matrix = np.array(
            [
                [100, 200, 0, 0, 164],
                [134, 682, 417, 8, 391],
                [0, 133, 780, 0, 0],
                [396, 76, 96, 214, 0],
            ], 
            dtype=np.int16,
        )

dense_matrix[2:4,2:] = np.clip(dense_matrix[2:4,2:], 0, 100)
```

This gives me `dense_matrix` as

```
array([[100, 200,   0,   0, 164],
       [134, 682, 417,   8, 391],
       [  0, 133, 100,   0,   0],
       [396,  76,  96, 100,   0]], dtype=int16)
```

Is there a way to do the same with a sparse matrix? Apart from going over the `index` and `indptr` and manually clipping the `data` if the index was in the slice, the only option I could think of is making a copy of the data and working with the `data` of the slice, like the code below:

```
sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(dense_matrix)
temp_slice = sparse_matrix[2:4,2:] 
temp_slice.data =  np.clip(temp_slice.data, 0, 97)
sparse_matrix[2:4,2:] = temp_slice
sparse_matrix.todense()
```

Which gives me

```
matrix([[100, 200,   0,   0, 164],
        [134, 682, 417,   8, 391],
        [  0, 133,  97,   0,   0],
        [396,  76,  96,  97,   0]], dtype=int16)
```

Is there a better way to do this that can avoid copying the slice?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Slices of `sparse` are not views; in general cases they are actually produced with matrix multiplication, not `numpy` style indexing.    I suppose you could try to find the 'flat' indices or the relevant `data` values, and modify the `sparse_matrix[indices]=...`, but I haven't thought through that kind of calculation.